# How to create a ready-for-printing document from multiple images

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

I want to print an [ebook](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/) using Ubuntu 18.10, but instead of a PDF file I have a folder with subfolders (chapters) containing individual jpg images (book pages).

How do I print it on paperback? I thought of somehow combining the images into a PDF file (order matters of course).

Inside the book folder: (using ubuntu Nautilus)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJJKM.png

Inside subfolder: (every subfolder has files with same names)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJJKM.png

Comment: Try `pdftk` (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - `available for Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8`

Comment: @cipricus ... and MacOS, CentOS, Red Hat, and source code known to compile and run on Debian, Ubuntu Linux, FreeBSD, Slackware Linux, SuSE, Solaris and HP-UX.

Comment: @cipricus Your list matches the list for "PDFtk Free" (the GUI) at that URL. Down further on that page is "PDFtk Server" (the command-line version). That's the one you want.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - is that a CLI-only tool?

Comment: @cipricus "Server" is the name of the original CLI tool "pdftk" , yes.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - is there some GUI for Linux? I have installed in Mint (https://askubuntu.com/a/1165823/925128) but gui-only I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101759/discussion-between-l-scott-johnson-and-cipricus).

Answer (score 2):

Either of the Open Source apps [Scribus](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) and [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/) allows you to place, align, and size the JPG images exactly where you want them, with pagination so images are not split between pages, and so you can add text and other graphics. Both will output to PDF, including archival format if desired.  Scribus even [lists printers known to accept its files electronically for printing](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus_Friendly_Print_Shops).

[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/help), another Open Source app, can convert your PDF file (and many other formats) into other ebook formats such as EPUB and MOBI.

Please note your Ubuntu [18.10 will no longer be supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes) next month, so please plan to upgrade to 19.04 (the current interim release), change to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ([supported until April 2023](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)), or make other arrangements for support.

You may also find the [Ebooks Stack Exchange site](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/) helpful once you get into the intricacies of formatting, and how to deal with print shops.

Answer (score 0):

So, the OP has some images — which the OP wants **to print**: that is why the OP is looking for a printable file format like pdf. It is not clear *whether* the OP still has the ebook as a file (and in *which* format), or just the images.

For printing the images one **doesn't need to create a new file** out of them first: open them in an image viewer like gThumb (Pix, Shotwell, Gwenview, etc)

[image]

and print them from there

[image]

**One can even re-arange the images before printing!**

Just drag & drop:

[image]

---

*If a **pdf** is really needed in order to print*:

- create pdf file **from the images**:

  - the simplest way is, as said above, to open images within an image browser/viewer like gThumb and then ***print them to pdf*** (selecting location and then "print to file"):

[image]

There are many other methods to create a pdf out of images with some script using a CLI tool or even with GUIs like [`gscan2pdf`](https://itsfoss.com/convert-multiple-images-pdf-ubuntu-1304/) but I have found those rather heavy on resources when using many images, taking a lot of time and even freezing the computer. A rather good method I used for that purpose was [this](http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/338-ubuntu-generate-pdf-from-documents)  — but now the above method seems preferable to me.)

- create pdf file **from an ebook**:

  - if the ebook file is not available, create an ebook — as indicated [here](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/305/13434) —  that is, not `epub` etc, but  `CBZ or CBR. These are standard ZIP or RAR files (the only difference is that their extension has been renamed)`; so: select the images, zip/rar them, rename the resulting archive to change extension from `zip` (or `rar`) to `cbz`;
  - [install Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux), and then open `cbz` file in the E-book Viewer that comes with Calibre. Right click and select print, then print to pdf.

[image]