# How to turn lots of images into 1 pdf without running out of resources

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion

I'm trying to convert thousands of jpg images into 1 big PDF. Each image is a page from a book.
I tried using the following command:

```
convert * out.pdf
```

But I'd get this error after maybe 150 images:

```
convert-im6.q16: DistributedPixelCache '127.0.0.1' @ error/distribute-cache.c/ConnectPixelCacheServer/244. 
convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted `0-23/3_014.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3984. ... 
convert-im6.q16: too many exceptions (exception processing suspended).
```

And yes, I changed resource limit in the policy.xml file for imagemagick to 8GiB.
I have a decent laptop. 8GB RAM, 2.4hz x 4, 2GB GPU

There are about 3000 images, a total of 1GB

Is there another way?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527532/how-to-create-an-ebook-from-multiple-images as the programs cited there do not rely on the resources which convert consumes so rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will work, but you might try a two-step procedure, as follows.

First, separately **convert** each jpg image into its own pdf,

> convert image1.jpg image1.pdf
>   convert image2.jpg image2.pdf
>   etc

Then use **pdfjam** (man pdfjam for info) to collect all the images
into a single pdf,

> pdfjam image*.pdf --outfile allimages.pdf

And see http://go.warwick.ac.uk/pdfjam (as suggested on the manpage) for lots more --switches, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The method most low on resources that I have found is to open images in an image viewer/browser (**gThumb, Pix, Gwenview, Shotwell**) and then **print them to file** - that is to **pdf**.

More details - with images - here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555535/341192. Images can also be re-aranged in this way before "printing" to pdf.

A rather light method (compared to other CLI ones, but maybe not to the above I mentioned) is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263661/341192).